# Migrating Multisite - Database error, missing wp_blogs table

Tags: multisite, database, errors, migration

I am trying to duplicate my WordPress multisite on local with Xampp, but I get error.

This are the steps I follow(I will use example instead of my website name):

- Copy all WordPress 4.0 files to htdocs/projects/example (the directory on I want to have this project)
- Create the  database "example"
- follow the steps to install wordpress
- Configure multisite network (all work fine up to this step, a new/blank multisite works correct)
- Replace the wp-content folder
- Delete all database tables and import the online database (previously exported)
- I use [Search and Replace DB plugin](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB) to replace all instances of the domains with localhost/projects/example

I have to say that I have do some migration before of a normal WordPress install and I have once migrate this same multisite to a new host and domain and all work correctly!

The database connection data is correct, the required tables are there, including wp_blogs table and all the domains seems to be changed, so where can be the error?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Where are you seeing it?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I have been able of import the database succesfully. Because my path is localhost/projects/example and no only localhost, after doing the replace with the plugin I have to manually change some tables path.

On wp_blogs and wp_site tables I have:

- Domain = localhost/projects/example
- Path = /

I have to change to:

- Domain = localhost
- Path = /projects/example/

And now it works perfectly!!

If somebody know about a way to do this change automaticaly I will love to read it.